# Baking with multiple Maps Question

Tags: uv

I'm new. 
I recently grabbed an av skeleton from a [game's wiki](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Mesh/Rigging_Fitted_Mesh) and wanted to know how I can select the uv maps separately? As in, just tapping L to highlight them. I had cut the edges of the mesh to separate it, but I ended up with this break in smoothness between parts. So I went back and marked the seams... voila! I can select them individually with L. So now the question is, how do I get it to bake ONLY the highlighted UV mapped area instead of all 3? Answered! Made multi materials. Now it's baking black:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question with well chosen Blender screen captures. At this point I find your words above a Confusing UV question.   The current image is not useful. Please carefully choose your words and [spelling] to conform to Blender jargon and [not] your personal jargon.    Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-Zkt3uAeO0 . Please see 3 tutorials of your choosing.

Comment: alright, edited it. I hope I'm more clear.

Comment: Give each part of the mesh its own material (head, upper body and lower body) and create a new image for each of those to bake to. Then bake each one separately.

Comment: okay, done! Though, the textures are baking black, updated with new screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This time I'm adding screenshots :)

Once you have your model assigned the 3 materials

1: Select the Head material.

2: In the UV/Image editor, create a new image for the head to bake to.

3: In the Node editor add a New Image node and select the Head image as reference.

[image]

Repeat for the other 2 materials.

Note: It is very important that you leave the Image node selected (highlighted) for each material. If an Image node is not selected then that material will not be baked !

4: Select all of the mesh.

5: When you have your baking options setup hit the Bake button. All 3 materials will be baked, each to its own image.

When the baking is finished only one of the three will be visible in the UV/image editor.

[image]

6: Go to the UV/Image editor and one by one select each of the three images and save them some where for later use.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I did it just like that! Well, almost. My Image node was connected to the color of the Diffuse Node. So what is the significance of it baking black if their connected vs not?

Comment: When the Image Texture node is connected you are telling Cycles to use that Image as a texture on your mesh. If the Image is a plane black texture (New image created in the UV editor) then you will end up with a black textured mesh. Baking out a Combined bake will result in a Black texture ! Black in Black out :) . Baking out an AO will (should) bake correctly because AO is not dependent on texture or lighting.